# Twitter Bootstrap, Image overwrite on Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use this [Bootstrap Vertical Thumbnail Carousel](https://github.com/tutorialdrive/Bootstrap-3-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel) source for create bootstrap thumbnail vertical carousel, Its work in like charm in Firefox and Safari (Latest version) but not in chrome.

Issue is in firefox and safari when press next or pre. button, current bunch of image scroll and after new one come. But in chrome Second bunch come first and place over First one and after that First bunch disappear,

**Here Is My Code** And **[JS Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9rnLgLvg/1/)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Thumbnail Slider</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body data-twttr-rendered="true" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="span8">

                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>

                    <div class="well" >

                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" >
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><img src="icon/up.png"></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><img src="icon/down.png"></a>

                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/1.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/2.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/3.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/4.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                                </div><!--/item-->

                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/5.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/6.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/7.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/8.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                                </div><!--/item-->

                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/9.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/10.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/11.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><div class="span3"><a href="#x" style = " width:50px; " class="thumbnail"><img src="image/12.gif" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%; width:50px;"></a></div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
                                </div><!--/item-->

                            </div><!--/carousel-inner-->     

                        </div><!--/myCarousel-->

                    </div><!--/well-->
                </div>
            </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems this problem is with the repo css itself. The file provided by the git hub is having the same issue. If you raise this question on the repo you will get a quick response.

Comment: @Kshitiz thanks for your valuable comment, but I am new to git. that repo. is my and can you guide me for that what you suggest me ?

Comment: For css some time same css behave differently on different browser. You need to check what css you should write for chrome browser. You might see the same css behave differently on explorer.

Will take a look at your code and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem it that the carousel container (`#myCarousel`) doesn't have an explicit height. Its child `.carousel-inner` has `height:100%`, but since `#myCarousel` doesn't have explicit height, this percentage value has no effect, as do %-based offsets of carousel items.

The quickest solution is to set the height mentioned:

```
#myCarousel{
    height:380px; /* or em, or some other fixed value*/
}

/* OR */

.carousel-inner{
    height:380px;/* or em, or some other fixed value*/
}
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/9rnLgLvg/5/)

Bu it is not very flexible: if you need to change the number or size of elements, this height needs to also be changed.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for, n ya. no worry about its flexibility. I'll manage it. Thanks one again